# "A disk read error occured" after installing Windows 7 from Samsung System Recovery Media on second disk (new SSD)

Tags: windows-7, installation

I have Samsung RC730 (NP-RC730-S02PL) laptop. I bought a second disk - SSD OCZ Agility. I wanted to install Windows 7 from Samsung System Recovery Media which I got with my laptop. I also noticed that my primary HDD has hidden partition which contains some Samsung files.

Does DVD Samsung System Recovery Media copies parts of Windows 7 from this hidden partition when you install fresh Windows 7? This is why I think so:

When I installed it on my SSD I got "A disk read error occured", and when installation was going on, there was some steps on installation which was skipped: copying files, function installations, updates installation, finishing installation. Only step that wasn't skipped was "unpacking data" (or something similar).

Is this DVD broken? Can I install Windows from it only on my primary HDD which contains hidden partition with Samsung files?
What can I do to install my Windows 7 on my new SSD?

While I can't boot Windows 7 from the SSD, I can boot to an old HDD to old Windows installation and browse the SSD without any errors, so the SSD is working OK.

Answer (score 4):

I would say to try the installation again.

Have you removed the old HDD before trying to install? It may make the DVD copy what it needs to the only hard drive available, your SSD. How large is your SSD drive? Have you run a `CHKDSK` or similar tool on the SSD?

To test the DVDs out, try copying all the files to a folder on your hard drive (In Windows 7's command prompt: `ROBOCOPY`*`x:`*`c:\test /s /eta /xj /r:0 /w:0`, replacing the *x:* with your DVD drive letter)

Comment: I installed it twice - once with old HDD plugged, and once with old HDD unplugged. My SSD is 120 GB (I made 105 GB partition for Windows). I will try copying and CHKDSK.

Comment: When I copy entire DVD without errors how can I check if all files I need to install windows 7 are here?

Comment: @SuitUp That test just shows that the DVD can be read without issues. If the DVD installs fine to the old hard drive, then the DVD is fine, and the path UP TO the hard drive is fine

Comment: I didn't installed Windows from this DVD on old HDD - I got laptop with preinstalled Windows.

Comment: ROBOCOPY shows that DVD is ok - it still can be true that I can install windows only on primary hdd with hidden samsung partition...

Comment: @suit up it's possible, but very unlikely